# Vue error page not showing up when using class bindings

Tags: vue.js

I have an error page that shows up if a city is not found. It has been working perfectly until I decided to make the background dynamic based on the result of the search. Now, the entire `app-bg` div is gone if the error triggers. Here is the relevant code:

Template

```
<div
  :class="{ nightBg: isNight(weather.weather[0].icon) }"
  class="app-bg"
>
  <div v-if="error">
    <router-link to="/">
      <i class="fa fa-times close-icon"></i>      
    </router-link>
    <div class="handleError">
      <h1>Uh-oh!</h1>
      <img src="../assets/errorIcon.png" alt="Error Icon">
      <h3>
        We couldn't find {{ this.$route.params.city }}
      </h3>
      <p>
        Check your spelling and try again!
      </p>      
    </div>
  </div>
  . . .
</div>
```

Script

```
export default {
  name: 'Result',
  data(){
    return {
      error: null,
      weather: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(`${this.$route.params.city}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.weather = response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  },
  methods: {
    . . .,
    isNight(iconID) {
      if(iconID.slice(2) == 'd') {
        return false;
      } if(iconID.slice(2) == 'n') {
        return true;
      } else { return false; }
    }
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.nightBg {
    background: #000000;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%, #7f466e 61%, #fc8a8a 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #000000 0%,#7f466e 61%,#fc8a8a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #000000 0%,#7f466e 61%,#fc8a8a 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#fc8a8a',GradientType=0 );
}
```

EDIT:

I changed the binding on the div to `<div :class="['app-bg', { nightBg: isNight }]">` and added the `isNight` method to the computed section, as shown below. `this.weatherIcon` is returning what I expect, but when I look at the Vue extension on Firefox, it shows `isNight: (error during evaluation)`, and the `app-bg` disappears.

```
export default {
  name: 'Result',
  data(){
    return {
      error: null,
      weather: null,
      weatherIcon: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(`${this.$route.params.city}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.weather = response.data;
        this.weatherIcon = this.weather.weather[0].icon;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  },
  computed: {
    isNight: () => {
      if(this.weatherIcon.slice(2) == 'n') {
        return true;
      } if(this.weatherIcon.slice(2) == 'd') {
        return false;
      } else { return false; }
    }
  },
  . . .
```

Comment: Not sure if you just left it out when you pasted your code, but your ```<div class="app-bg">``` is missing a closing tag.  Also, what is the CSS content of your 'nightBg' class?

Comment: I just forgot to add it in the question, but I updated it to include the ending `div` and the CSS

Comment: `weather.weather[0].icon` won't be set if it's not returned, it would be showing errors in the console

Comment: also clean up `:class="['app-bg', { nightBg: isNight }]"`, dont need 2 classes and should use computed prop, not a method

Comment: What is the difference in using computed and a method?

Comment: @supernova Methods are executed every time they are called.  Computed properties are cached and only re-evaluated if one of the values they depend on changes.